# 2 level combobox

Tags: extjs

Is it possible to create multilevel combobox using ExtJS 4.0? I mean, that it should have, for example, these options:

- **This**
- Month
- Year
- **Last**
- Month
- Year

**This** and **Last** options should be **not** selectable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This absolutely is possible.

You can define a template for your combobox which defines how the row is displayed. What you can do is have the store have a field which defines the type of record, such as a boolean header field.

In your xTemplate which you pass into the Combobox's tpl config, you can check the value of that field and if it's a header apply separate styling. Then, add a beforeselect listener and if the record's header field is true, return false.

I saw something similar on the Ext website, but can't locate it right now. If you need more details, let me know.